# What cable standard is needed for UL94V-0 device

Tags: cables, ul

I'm designing a device that has UL94V-0 rated plastic parts. So far so good. But there are also a number of cables inside the enclosure and cables use different ratings..

What would match UL94V-0 in terms of flammability? FT-1? FT-4? VW-1?

**update**
On more research it appears CSA FT4 is unreasonable as it's for long building runs so most likely candidates are CSA FT1, UL VW-1 and IEC 332-1.

If someone's really interested, here's comparison of the various standards: 
http://www.lappusa.com/Cableatt-Flame.htm

And what goes on in IEC60332 tests:
http://www.leoni-industrial-projects.com/fileadmin/bu/ip/pdf_-_technische_Infos/BRANDTST_ENGL_2008.pdf

Finally, a post from 1999 about this very subject:
https://www.mail-archive.com/emc-pstc@listserv.ieee.org/msg10570.html

Even more cable burning info:
http://www.caledonian-cables.net/product/Technical%20Lib/Fire%20Performance%20Testing.htm#U

And the obligatory video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z__CfyGQ4IU

Comment: A brief explanation of the cable fire standards. https://goo.gl/L7Ow5Y

Comment: If you found information that's better than mine (looks like you did) you can post an answer to your own question. But it would be better to summarize the information you found rather than just give links (which might go bad in the future).

Comment: http://iq.ul.com/awm/ should help once you know, then find a wire style to suit.. i use vw-1 and 90 degC as search parameters.

Comment: @ThePhoton You answer made me think the right way i.e. comb the relevant safety standard for mention of cable specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IEC 61010, the requirement is

> Insulated wires and cables shall retard flame propagation.
>
> NOTE 2 Wire with a flammability RATING of UL 2556 VW-1 or equivalent is considered to meet this
>   requirement.

This is part (b) of a paragraph where part (a) calls for PWB's to be rated V-2 or better (V-0 being better than V-2).

IEC 61010 is the IEC safety specification for test and measurement equipment. Your application probably requires meeting some other specification. Although many standards have similar requirements, you should check the standards appropriate for your application to see whether they match or not.

Comment: A fair cop. In this case IEC62368 (or IEC60950) are appropriate. At least IEC62368 does not specify anything about cable materials although it goes into details about fire barriers and such. A bit daft making a flameproof enclosure and traversing it with any old wire.. In this case I'd probably have to look into the UL equivalents to see those UL/CSA cable codes. IEC60332-2-2 and IEC TS 60695-11-21 define the tests but that does not really help with what you're looking at when shopping for cables

Comment: I found a reference in IEC TR 62368-2:2015 page 72 that says: 
Exemptions:
– Wire and tubing insulation complying with IEC 60332 series or IEC 60695-11-21
So as far as IEC is concerned IEC 332-1 ribbon cable should be good enough for high power LED driver. Too bad someone asking for (unreasonable) UL94V-0 probably wants to see "UL" or at least CSA.

Comment: Sorry I only have access to the one standard. Compared to the cost of re-doing a test at your NRTL, it's not very expensive to buy a copy of an IEC standard.

Comment: Well, it's not so much matter of buying the standard rather than knowing *which* standard and then finding the relevant bit. In this case the key information was contained in the "explanatory information" technical report add-on to IEC 62368-1, not in the actual standard. I could fork out for UL 60950 in hopes of finding a mention to either of the North American standards. A bit pricey gamble since the UL version of 60950 costs more than twice as much as the IEC version. but I think I go with IEC 332-1 and the VW-1 / FT1. Würth has all of those for same ribbon cable..
https://goo.gl/L7Ow5Y

Answer (score 0):

Summarising some of the comments and links.

Asking "What's equivalent of UL94V-0" is not really meaningful as UL94 level is defined by a safety standard. That safety standard then defines (maybe) the cable specification as well. You can correlate from V-0 requirement to cable spec requirement **if** the product actually requires V-0 from safety point of view.

In our case V-0 classification is just a magic number to put on marketing material, from safety point of view V-2 is sufficient.

IEC 60332-1 vertical flame application test is broadly equivalent of CSA FT1 and the easier version of UL VW-1 test. VW-1 has unhelpfully two levels of test, one with 5 applications of 15 seconds of flame and the harder test is 20 minutes of scorching. IEC 60332-1 defines 60 seconds of burning for cable diameter <25mm and 120 seconds for >= 25mm. FT1 is essentially the same as VW-1 (5x 15 seconds).

IEC 62368 safety standard for IT equipment has technical report add-on that explicitly mentions IEC 60332-1 cable being suitable for use with high power power supplies. UL 60950 has it's own definitions for cables allowed to traverse "fire block" which I have no knowledge of.